# Adding different suffix's to number counters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm displaying a number of stats on a page. The numbers animate as you scroll down the page.

Some stats require a "+" or a "%" after the number. I can only seem to apply the same character to all counters but need to target specific ones with a "+", "%" or nothing at all. So my question is how do I target a specific counter with a specific suffix?

Below is the code I've used for four counters without suffix's. Can I just add some extra code to this? I'm quite new to coding so any help would be much appreciated!

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {

var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
$('.counter-value').each(function() {
var $this = $(this),
countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
$({
countNum: $this.text()
}).animate({
countNum: countTo
},
{
duration: 2000,
easing: 'swing',
step: function() {
$this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum).toLocaleString("en-US"));
},
complete: function() {
$this.text(this.countNum.toLocaleString("en-US"));
}
});
});
a = 1;
}
});
</script>
<div id="counter">
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-1 counter-value" data-count="30000" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-2 counter-value" data-count="135" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-3 counter-value" data-count="18" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-4 counter-value" data-count="100" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
</div>
<style>     
 .counter-value-1 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #A42B28;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-1:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
   .counter-value-2 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #EA7326;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-2:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  .counter-value-3 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #24B24B;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-3:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
   .counter-value-4 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #A9CF39;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-4:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set extra data field `data-suffix` to last two elements So I can find that suffix when looping through elements and use it as well:

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {

var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
   $('.counter-value').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this),
   countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
   $({
   countNum: $this.text()
   }).animate({
   countNum: countTo
   },
   {
   duration: 2000,
   easing: 'swing',
   step: function() {
   var suffix=$this.data("suffix");
   $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum).toLocaleString("en-US") +suffix);
   },
   complete: function() {
   var suffix=$this.data("suffix");
   $this.text(this.countNum.toLocaleString("en-US") + suffix);
   }
});
});
a = 1;
}
});
</script>
<div id="counter">
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-1 counter-value" data-count="30000" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-2 counter-value" data-count="135" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-3 counter-value" data-count="18" data-desc="countries surveyed in" data-suffix="%">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-4 counter-value" data-count="100" data-desc="countries surveyed in" data-suffix="%">0</div>
</div>
<style>     
 .counter-value-1 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #A42B28;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-1:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
   .counter-value-2 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #EA7326;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-2:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  .counter-value-3 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #24B24B;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-3:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
   .counter-value-4 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #A9CF39;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-4:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Do you know how you'd be able to add an icon above each number?

Comment: If you need a single icon so it is better to set it using HTML not jquery. If you insist on jquery so you should use `.html()` instead of `.text()`  and write html codes inside it like this : `.html('<img src="icon.png">')`

Comment: If the answers was useful you can vote up or accept answers

Answer (score 0):

How about you bind the character as an attribute, same way you bound the counts and descriptions?

```js
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {

var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
$('.counter-value').each(function() {
var $this = $(this),
countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
$({
countNum: $this.text()
}).animate({
countNum: countTo
},
{
duration: 2000,
easing: 'swing',
step: function() {
$this.text((Math.floor(this.countNum).toLocaleString("en-US")) + $this.attr('data-character'));
},
complete: function() {
$this.text((this.countNum.toLocaleString("en-US")) + $this.attr('data-character'));
}
});
});
a = 1;
}
});
```

```css
 .counter-value-1 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #A42B28;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-1:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
   .counter-value-2 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #EA7326;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-2:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
  .counter-value-3 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #24B24B;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-3:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
   .counter-value-4 { 
   font-family: Georgia;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #A9CF39;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 17px 0;
 }
  .counter-value-4:after {
   content: attr(data-desc);
    display: block;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.2em;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="counter">
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-1 counter-value" data-character="+" data-count="30000" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-2 counter-value" data-character="%" data-count="135" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-3 counter-value" data-character="-" data-count="18" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
    <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-3 counter-value-4 counter-value" data-character="*" data-count="100" data-desc="countries surveyed in">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how you'd be able to add an icon above each number?